# Can't stop animation at end of one cycle

Tags: animation, webkit, css

I'm making a CSS animation at the minute, and in it I'm moving stuff and want it to stay at the end position until the user moves their mouse away.

```
body {
    background: url('osx.jpg');
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 60px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes item1 {
    0% { bottom: -120px; left: 0px; }
    10% { bottom: -40px; left: 10px; -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); }
    100% { bottom: -40px; left: 10px; -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); }
    }

@-webkit-keyframes item2 {
    0% { bottom: -120px; left: 0px; }
    10% { bottom: 60px; left: 20px; -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); }
    100% { bottom: 60px; left: 20px; -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes item3 {
    0% { bottom: -120px; left: 0px; }
    10% { bottom: 160px; left: 30px; -webkit-transform: rotate(9deg); }
    100% { bottom: 160px; left: 30px; -webkit-transform: rotate(9deg); }
}

    div {
    position: relative;
    }
#folder {
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#folder > div {
    position: absolute; 
}

#folder:hover > div:nth-of-type(1) {
    -webkit-animation-name: item1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
}

#folder:hover > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-animation-name: item2;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
}

#folder:hover > div:nth-of-type(3) {
    -webkit-animation-name: item3;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
}
```

Whenever the animation ends though, it just repeats itself. I only want it to happen once and stay where it is until the user moves away. I tried using the paused thing from the spec but it doesn't work as I'd expect it to. Any help is appreciated. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The following comment worked for me.  Thanks michael

"You need to add the fill-mode to freeze the animation state at the end of the animation.

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

`forwards` leaves the animation in the state of the last frame

`backwards` leaves the animation at the start

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but the correct way actualy is animation-play-state: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state

Answer (score 19):

Just in case your animation still resets to the first frame, be careful with the **order** in which you declare the css:

This is working fine:

```
    animation: yourAnimationName 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

This won't (reset to first frame):

```
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation: yourAnimationName 1s;
```

Tricky!

Comment: Thank you! Any reason for why this is?

Comment: That happens because `animation` is shorthand for all `animation-*` properties and setting `animation` will overwrite all `animation-*` properties. This behavior is identical to other shorthands (e.g. `background` or `border`). If you use `animation` shorthand and do not define fill mode, then `none` will be used by default.

Comment: Great point! I had no clue why was this happening to me!

Comment: You can combine it like this one-liner

`animation: 1s ease 0s normal forwards 1 running yourAnimationName;`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, it sounds like you need to set the iteration to '1'.

```
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

Comment: That was it, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

The css3 animations reset to the default style at the end of the animation. You can try something with javascript:

You can add an eventListener to your animation, retrieve the styles you wish to keep, apply them manually and remove the animation.

```
document.getElementById('yourdiv').addEventListener(
    'webkitAnimationEnd',
    function(){
        document.getElementById('yourdiv').style.backgroundPosition = '0px 0px';
        document.getElementById('yourdiv').style.webkitAnimationName = 'none';
    }, 
    false
);
```

Comment: this is true, but the experiment I was carrying out was to try and do it with just CSS. Thanks for trying though

Comment: You need to add the fill-mode to freeze the animation state at the end of the animation. "-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards" You shouldn't just make the animation super long - that will chew up your users CPU - CSS animations are very CPU intensive.

Comment: @Michael Interesting! Thanks for this, I didn't know it existed. I will try it and will certainly use it in my next projects.

Comment: @MichaelMullany I think the fact CSS3 animations are CPU intensive does not apply anymore. Browsers will try to use GPU acceleration as much as possible if you use 3D transforms in animations, which you should always do.

Comment: Agreed. This was back in the day. Just edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
-webkit-animation-duration: 10s, 10s;
```

:)

Comment: will animate over 10 seconds and left over 10 seconds.

Comment: Still nothing, I decided to make the animation really long instead (like 10,000s long) so that the users unlikely to hover over it for that length of time ;D