# Stopping a CSS3 Animation on last frame

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a 4 part CSS3 animation playing on click  - but the last part of the animation is meant to take it off the screen.

However, it always goes back to its original state once it has played. Anyone know how I can **stop it on its last css frame (100%)**, or else how to get rid of the whole div it is in once it has played.

```
@keyframes colorchange {
  0%   { transform: scale(1.0) rotate(0deg); }
  50%  { transform: rotate(340deg) translate(-300px,0px) }
  100% { transform: scale(0.5) rotate(5deg) translate(1140px,-137px); }
}
```

Comment: Hey Nick, can you post the css and html you are using?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, i have updated my question with the css and javascript. The only html i am using is a div with an onclick to start the function rotate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't stop animation at end of one cycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087360/cant-stop-animation-at-end-of-one-cycle)

Answer (score 482):

You're looking for:

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

[More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) and browser support list on [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation).

Comment: Do you know if that works in chrome? Not having any luck with it

Comment: Please accept this as the correct answer. More explanation on this one: http://4waisenkinder.de/blog/2014/10/13/control-your-css-animations-with-animation-fill-mode/

Comment: @user531192 For Chrome/Webkit browsers you have to use 
`-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

Comment: Chrome doesn't need the -webkit- prefix anymore now (at least from v49)

Comment: One issue I had with this was I didn't have a `100% {}` or `to {}` set, so even with `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` my animation would still dump me at `0%`. (I was using some @for loops to create my animations and forgot to manually add a `from{}`and `to{}`);

Comment: Just one important warning: `animation-fill-mode` property must be after `animation` prop to works.

Comment: @mikep - Technically, yes. But not for the reasons you might think. `animation` is a shorthand property for all nine animation CSS properties `animation-<sub-property>`. So when you use `animation`, it'll overwrite any `animation-*` properties that came before it (as CSS reads top-to-bottom through your styles).

Answer (score 48):

If you want to add this behaviour to a shorthand `animation` property definition, the order of sub-properties is as follows

`animation-name` - *default* `none`

`animation-duration` - *default* `0s`

`animation-timing-function` - *default* `ease`

`animation-delay` - *default* `0s`

`animation-iteration-count` - *default* `1`

`animation-direction` - *default* `normal`

`animation-fill-mode` - **you need to set this to** `forwards`

`animation-play-state` - *default* `running`

Therefore in the most common case, the result will be something like this

```
animation: colorchange 1s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
```

See the [MDN documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

Answer (score 35):

> ```
> -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
> animation-fill-mode: forwards;
> ```

**Browser Support**

- Chrome 43.0 (4.0 -webkit-)
- **IE  10.0**
- Mozilla 16.0 ( 5.0 -moz-)
- Shafari   4.0 -webkit-
- Opera 15.0 -webkit- (12.112.0 -o-)

**Usage:-**

```
.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;

    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;

    animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;

     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way seems to put the final state at the main part of css. Like here, i put width to `220px`, so that it finally becomes `220px`. But starting to `0px;`

```
div.menu-item1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 220px;
  animation: slide 1s;
  -webkit-animation: slide 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide { /* Safari and Chrome */
  from {width:0px;}
  to {width:220px;}
}
```

Comment: This is great, the best way to deal with this problem I think.

Comment: If you use an animation-delay, it starts with the end state, resets to 0%, then animates to 100%. Not ideal and visually jarring.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't your issue that you're setting the webkitAnimationName back to nothing so that's resetting the CSS for your object back to it's default state.  Won't it stay where it ended up if you just remove the setTimeout function that's resetting the state?

Answer (score 1):

I just posted a similar answer, and you probably want to have a look at:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-events-

You can find out aspects of an animation, such as start and stop, and then, once say the 'stop' event has fired you can do whatever you want to the dom.  I tried this out some time ago, and it can work, but I'd guess you're going to be restricted to webkit for the time being (but you've probably accepted that already).  Btw, since I've posted the same link for 2 answers, I'd offer this general advice: check out the W3C - they pretty much write the rules and describe the standards.  Also, the webkit development pages are pretty key.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody actualy brought it so, the way it was made to work is [animation-play-state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state) set to paused.

Answer (score -1):

I learned today that there is a limit you want to use for the fill-mode. This is from an Apple dev. Rumor is * around * six, but not certain.
Alternatively, you can set the initial state of your class to how you want the animation to end, then * initialize * it at from / 0% .