# Is it possible to CSS animate relative values, I.e. width: 100%

Tags: css

I'm reading up on CSS animations/keyframes and since I always like to start with relative values, I put together this:

```
div.frame {
    animation-name: saturn;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    background-color: rgba(128, 255, 128, 1);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* animations */
@keyframes saturn {
    from {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    to {
        width: 90%;
        height: 90%;
    }
}
```

And this produces exactly no result, just a plain-old green full screen div.

Can CSS be given relative sizes for animations, I.e. percentages of parents? Or is it the same story as with jQuery `.animate()`?

Comment: [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Znndp/1/)?

Comment: @Vucko yes exactly like this, please explain what I've missed and post an answer so that I can accept it and upvote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example , you just have 2 errors:

Put :

```
html, body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

So the `div` can use it's parents `width` and `height`.

And use *prefixes* for **CSS3 animations**

Example:

```
-webkit-animation-name: saturn;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-moz-animation-name: saturn;
-moz-animation-duration: 5s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

[Fiddle of your example](http://jsfiddle.net/MycT2/)

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/css-animation)

**Note** : use `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` so the animation won't return to original state when it finishes. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359627/stopping-a-css3-animation-on-last-frame)

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I do get a fullscreen div, so that implies I do have `html,body` set to 100% :). Other than that, thanks!

Comment: I was testing with your code and that was missing so sorry about that. :)
Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I´m new here, so maybe my answer is not the very best.

In CSS3 you can animate using Transitions.
Check this website (created by W3C) for more information: [CSS3 Transition / w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)

I hope this answer is a little bit helpful for you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) thanks for the heads-up on transitions, but it seems Vucko has the answer required.

Comment: w3schools.com isn't created by W3C and it's not a very recomendable resource. See [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) for more info.