# Stop animation at the end of nth-child / CSS3

Tags: css, key, css-animations

I have got an crossfading animation to show 3 steps of content. How could I make it so that it ends after the third one? so no more crossfading.

[CodePen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaxqGy)

I divided it into nth-child(),

Here's my CSS code:

```
.animation {
  -moz-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear 0s;
  -ms-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear 0s;
  -o-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear 0s;
  -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear 0s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  animation: imageAnimation 30s linear 0s;
  color: black;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.animation:nth-child(2) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.animation:nth-child(3) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="animation">
    <h4>Hello-1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="animation">
    <h4>Hello-2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="animation">
    <h4>Hello-3</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping a CSS3 Animation on last frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359627/stopping-a-css3-animation-on-last-frame)

Answer (score 1):

If you by "to end" mean that the 3rd child does not dissapear, you need to declare new animation `@keyframes` declaration that you use for that 3rd child, so it does not end (`100%`) with `opacity:0`.

**EDIT:**
This is how the new keyframes definition could look like:

```css
@keyframes imageAnimationStop {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

This says that the end state (`100%`) should have `opacity: 1` so it remains visible. I also forked your codepen. This new keyframe is not browser prefixed but I guess you can do that much :). Then you just need to use this new heyframes definition for your 3rd child [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPLyXz)

Comment: How would I do that? I'm pretty new to css3 animation