# Stand Animation Upon Completion in css

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Once the animation is finished, it will not stop and return to its original state
I want the width to stay at 46%

```css
.option{
 background: #c8d7f5;
 margin-top: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 5px;
 transition:width .5s;
}

#o1{
 animation: set 1s;
 width:2%;
}

@keyframes set{
 from{width:2%;}
 to{width:46%;}
}
```

```html
<div class='option' id='o1'>TEXT</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stopping a CSS3 Animation on last frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359627/stopping-a-css3-animation-on-last-frame)

Comment: As the comment above points out, this question is a duplicate. Please search for similar questions before asking. Refer to the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/) article for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

animation-fill-mode: forwards

or in this case, just use the shorthand of including "forwards" in your animation declaration

```css
.option{
 background: #c8d7f5;
 margin-top: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 5px;
 transition:width .5s;
}

#o1{
 animation: set 1s forwards;
 width:2%;
}

@keyframes set{
 from{width:2%;}
 to{width:46%}
}
```

```html
<div class='option' id='o1'>TEXT</div>
```